# How to create a click event handler for a reusable button

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a reusable composable like below,

```
@Composable
fun CustomButton(
    text : String
){
    Button(onClick = { },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(60.dp)
        ) {
        Text(text = text)
    }
}
```

I am using the composable button as shown below.
How can I implement a callback for `onclick` function?

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
        .padding(bottom = 32.dp)
) {
    CustomButton(text = "Get Started")
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(16.dp))
    CustomButton(text = "Log In")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this,

**Button**

```
@Composable
fun CustomButton(
    text: String,
    onClick: () -> Unit,
) {
    Button(
        onClick = onClick,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(60.dp),
    ) {
        Text(text = text)
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
        .padding(bottom = 32.dp)
) {
    CustomButton(text = "Get Started") {
        // Click event occurs here.
    }
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(16.dp))
    CustomButton(text = "Log In") {
        // Click event occurs here.
    }
}
```

Comment: If we are talking about reusable component - always pass the modifier. In your example the button will always fill max width. I'm 100% sure that this will be a limitation at some point. You should always pass the sizing from the outside to reusable components: https://chris.banes.dev/always-provide-a-modifier/

Comment: Yes, but I was just keeping things simple and copying the original code without getting side tracked on non-related issues. The post wasn't about being re-usable but about making a click event handler.

Comment: A lof of people will come here by title, which states "for reusable button". So I think it might get a wrong idea to some heads :)